# Continuity of Integral function

Tags: calculus

[image: Discontinuous function]

Let's say we have the above function. Here, the function is not defined for $x \in  (2,2.5)$.

Will the integral function $y=\int_{0}^{3} f(t) dt$ be continuous in $[0,3]$?

---

I believe that $y=\int_{0}^{2} f(t) dt= \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$, where $x \in (2,2.5]$. This is because the void contributes nothing. If we were to plot $y$ for $x \in [0,3]$,  we would see that its graph is horizontal and continuous for $x \in (2,2.5]$. And of course, $y$ is continuous everywhere else. In summary, I think that the integral function in this case is continuous in $[0,3]$. Is my reasoning appropriate?

Comment: It is true that the void contributes nothing but at the same time $\int_0^3 f(t)dt$ has no meaning if $f$ isn't defined on $(2,2.5)$, because then the limit of the Riemann sum doesn't make sense.

Comment: My initial approach was to break the interval into two intervals where Riemann sums exist and go ahead. I was just curious about the continuity of the integral function in this case.

Comment: Suppose you considered the function $(x+0.5)^2$ on $(2.5 \leq x \leq 3)$, which has the effect of pushing the blue curve to the left just the right amount, then yes your integral would be continuous.

Comment: Assuming $\int_0^3f(t)~dt$ exists, it is constant and therefore continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the integral function $y=\int_{0}^{3} f(t) dt$ be continuous in $[0,3]$?

If $f(t)$ is the function in your graph, then no, the integral function is not continuous on $[0,3]$ because it's not even defined on all of $[0,3]$.

> I believe that $y=\int_{0}^{2} f(t) dt= \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$, where $x \epsilon (2,2.5]$. This is because the void contributes nothing.

"Contributes nothing" isn't the right phrase here.  "Contributes nothing" would make sense if $f(t) = 0$ for $t \in (2,2.5).$  But $f$ isn't even defined on that interval.  So $f$ doesn't "contribute nothing," it simply just doesn't exist.  Talking about $\int_0^x f(t) \, dt$ for $x \in (2,2.5]$ doesn't make sense because the integrand isn't defined on $(2,2.5)$.

> If we were to plot $y$, we would see that its graph is horizontal and continuous for $x \in (2,2.5]$.

I disagree with this.  If we were to plot it, we would get nothing for $x \in (2,2.5)$ since the integrand isn't defined on $(2,2.5)$.  If you get something flat and horizontal on an interval, that means the integrand is zero on that interval.  But the integrand isn't zero there.  The integrand isn't defined at all there.

With all that said, note that the integral function is continuous on the intervals where the integral function is defined.  But it is not continuous on *all* of $[0,3]$.

Comment: This clears everything.

Answer (score 1):

The values you have inputted do not make sense, since $f$ is not defined on that interval. If, on the other hand you meant that $f=0$ on the interval $(2,2.5)$, then the integral would just be constant on that interval, and hence still continuous (by the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma).)

Comment: I did realize that. This helps.